# Stuck in "Take the Tour and earn your first badge"

Tags: bug

ai.meta.stackexchange.com is (correctly) showing that I have no badges.

It suggests "Take the Tour and earn your first badge".

I do that, and it says I've been awarded a badge.

But when I go back to the original page, it still says I have no badges and still suggests "Take the Tour and earn your first badge".

Is something broken here?

UPDATE:

As far as I know, the "meta" sites don't normally even offer a tour, much less keep insisting on it.

But now that I've submitted this question, the original problem has of course gone away and I've been awarded a "student" badge.

However, unlike all the other sites, I haven't been automatically awarded a "biographer" badge.  (E.g. expatriots.meta or travel.meta)

I really don't care about the badges themselves, but something unusual is happening on this site.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! I am not sure and I would need to check this, but you probably need to take some concrete action to get your first badge. By "concrete action" I mean an action such as asking a question, answering a question, or voting.

Comment: @RayButterworth I noticed something similar myself, not only on this site but on other ones, where this issue went away later, including as I recall in cases where I did nothing. I suspect the issue is most likely due to caching which is used in many places on the SE sites due to the relatively large number of queries which are executed and, especially on sites like StackOverflow & other larger ones (e.g., mathematics), the many people who are simultaneously using the sites.